# Find line to change in text file by conditions for lines before it

Tags: python, text

Is there a way in python to find and change a line in a text file for which the lines above it fulfill certain conditions? In particular consider a text file that looks like this:

```
dimensions      [0 1 -1 0 0 0 0];

internalField   uniform (0 0 0);

boundaryField
{
    inlet
    {
        type            fixedValue;
        value           uniform (0 0.6 0); 
    }
    outlet
    {
        type            inletOutlet;
        inletValue      uniform (0 0 0);
        value           uniform (0 0 0);
    }
}
```

In this file I would for example like to change the line that contains `value           uniform (0 0.6 0);`. The condition would be that it is the line that is inside `boundaryField` and inside `inlet` and begins (after stripping leading spaces) with `value`.

What is the best way to get the line index of this line to change it?

Comment: You could try some regex stuff but it will break in a instance anything changes .. To make it reliable you would need to parse that file properly. Apparently this is OpenFoam stuff ? There are multiple pypi packages that might help you with reading and modifying the contentn and writing the data back into the file. Go to https://pypi.org and search for openfoam

Comment: Okay so there is no (easy) way around importing PyFoam for stuff like that. That basically answers my question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks about compatible with Python's tokenization so you could just use `tokenize.generate_tokens`, then pseudo-parse the token stream, and extract the line number from the relevant tokens once you've found what you were looking for.

A more complicated but safer approach would be to create a full-blown parser, parse this to Python structures, update it in memory, then write it back.